# Scrollbar not working for Checkbox list

Tags: css

My CSS file has an `overflow-y` property but this property is not supported in `2.1` as it's a CSS3 property.

Please let me know an alternative for this property in `2.1`

The following is the code:

```
else if (multiselectbox)
{
     LiteralControl divStart = new LiteralControl("<div class='multiselectDiv'>");
       cell.Controls.Add(divStart);
       cell.Controls.Add(childControl);                        
       LiteralControl divEnd = new LiteralControl("</div>");
       cell.Controls.Add(divEnd);
}
```

and In css

```
.multiselectDiv
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
       height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't address both axis on their own in CSS2.1.

There is only normal `overflow` without `-x` or `-y`.

So if you want to allow only vertical scrolling you have to adjust your width in order that there is no horizontal overflow.

Comment: @DineshKumarSingh `#id { overflow: scroll; }` Will add a scrollbar to any overflow in your div.

Comment: Then you probably have to show your code. Edit your post doing this.

Comment: .multiselectDiv
{
    overflow:scroll;
    height:400px;               

}

I am calling the multiselectDiv in my cs file. Note if I reference any other css class for example a css class with background color its working fine. So basically there is a problem with multiselectDiv css class

Comment: And `multiselectDiv` is a class? I mean the elements where you want to add a scrollbar have `class=multiselectDiv`?

Comment: Yes class=multiselectDiv

Comment: Try  `overflow: auto;` if that doesn't work, do you use some very old browser? If yes try it again with Firefox or Chrome or any new one to check if really just the Scrollbar isn't working or sth else is wrong.

Comment: Something different must be wrong then. `overflow` is in CSS21 as you can see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

Comment: Apart from this is there any solution to add scroll bar for my checkboxlist which is dynamically rendered

Comment: Put your checkboxlist inside a div give the div a absolute height and add `overflow: scroll`

Comment: What do you have so far? I would advise yout to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33560937/edit) your question with your "multiselectDiv" and its css style.

Comment: `childControl` is your checkbox list?

Comment: Sorry to mention earlier...yes its checkboxlist